# Common UI to see the logs of different JVMs

Tags: java, logging

We have 4 boxes and each box is having 2 JVMs where our applications are deployed. There is a load balancer that can redirect request to any of the JVM.

Its very clumsy to open 8 putty session to see the log files when we need to analyze the issue.

Is there any way or open source that provides common UI to see the logs of different boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Logstash](http://logstash.net/) does just that. You can even parse and index the logs for retrieval later. There is also a WEB UI that lets you search the last X minutes of logs. Take a look at their [intro video and demo](http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.9/learn).

Comment: Thanks for the information. It looks good what I was expecting.